# XSD validation on multiple phone numbers

Tags: xml, xsd

I have this xml:
`

```
<ConsumerPhonenumbers>
<ConsumerPhonenumber>0612345678</ConsumerPhonenumber>
<ConsumerPhonenumber>+312012345678</ConsumerPhonenumber>
</ConsumerPhonenumbers>
```

`
The format of the phone number can be different.
Below is alloud
+310612345678  or
310612345678  or
31612345678  or
31612345678  or
0612345678  or
06.12345678  or
06-12345678
The number should be min 10 long and max 12
An empty ConsumerPhonenumber is also ok.

Now I have this in my xsd:
`

```
<xs:element name="ConsumerPhonenumber" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="5" nillable="false">
<xs:simpleType>
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="\+?\d[\d -]{8,12}\d"></xs:pattern>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

`

If I send an empty ConsumerPhonenumber it fails while it should be ok.

Two questions:

1. Is my pattern value ok?
2. How to accept empty ConsumerPhonenumber?

Thank you

Comment: try `\+?\d[\d -]{8,12}\d|^$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you LMC for the solution:

```
\+?\d[\d -]{8,12}\d|^$
```